# How to obtain data for the paginated set of django_tables2?

Tags: python, django-nonrel, django-tables2

I'm using [django_tables2](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

I am retrieving my records via:

```
table = ExampleTable(category.example_set.all(), order_by=('-uploaded_at',))
```

I wish to get the list of tables for the specific page from the table. I've tried:

```
rows = table.rows
```

but that gives me the complete record set from the query. I wish to only have the records that will display on the page (after django_tables took into consideration the page and size via the request config).

How do I get the specific rows from the table that will be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I found it in the html template:

```
table.page.object_list
```